# Highlighting lines in vim excluding the row number

Tags: vim, highlighting

I have `set number` in my vimrc, and I want to highlight rows using my mouse cursor without selecting the row numbers, kinda like how `MacVim` does it. I understand that `MacVim` is a native application and `vim` is bound by the conditions of the shell/terminal that it is in.

Is there a way to make this happen?

I want this:

[image: MacVim cursor highlight]

Not this:

[image: vim cursor highlight]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your terminal supports the mouse (some don't). Adding the following to your vimrc will enable the mouse to be used for visual selections.

```
set mouse=a
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!